# $q.all then getting called before resolving promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I have a `MainService` which makes a call to `default` method which returns me a `promise`.

```
default: (function() {
         var d = $q.all([
            service1.get(onFirstSuccess),
            service2.ret(onSecondSuccess)
         ]);

         function onFirstSuccess(){} 
         function onSecondSuccess(){}  
});
```

I am calling this `default` method from another `service`.

```
MainService.default().then(function(){
    console.log("this is getting called before onSecondSuccess");
});
```

The problem is before the `$q.all` gets complete, `then` function is being triggered here.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As Mr.Green said in his answer, you're not returning the promise from the default function so your outer `then` handler isn't chaining off of `d` at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
default: (function() {
    var d = $q.all([
      service1.get(onFirstSuccess),
      service2.ret(onSecondSuccess)
    ]);

  function onFirstSuccess(){} 
  function onSecondSuccess(){}          
   return d;
  });
```

may be you should return `d` in default function